# Automating slurm `sbatch`

Tags: c, linux, slurm, hpc

The story is this, I'm trying to run a simulation under different parameters. In order to run one of them, the following `.sh` is needed(**minimal example**).

About 1000 different simulations are needed, only the parameters are different. I could do this manually but I thought there must have something easier for this.

The desired behavior is submitting all jobs at once if possible.

The motivation to submit them separately is to leverage the power of HPC so that I can run all the simulations simultaneously. (I don't have a cap on this `normal partition` job in our server)

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=fastTest
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=20
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=3gb
#SBATCH --time=10:00:00
#SBATCH --account=***
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --output=%x.out
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=***

#######./a.out is a c program, the following are the arguments(parameters) passed to ./a.out.#### 

./a.out fileToSample.txt fileNameToSave.txt exam.txt 0.7 926
```

Thanks for your time. All suggestions or help are appreciated.

Comment: There is no actual question in your post. Ask a specific question. I cannot tell if you want some modification to that shell script to make it execute `a.out` 1000 times or if you want to execute that script 1000 times or something else. And what arguments should `a.out` be given so the 1000 executions are different? And why is this tagged C when there is no C code problem?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your suggestion. I will make it more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [job arrays](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will find out if it will work in my case and keep you posted.

Comment: It is exactly what I need. Although it does require some learning.